# how to perform arithmetic on fractions in a Linux module

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module, printk

I want to perform arithmetic on fractions, and I know that you can't perform floating-point arithmetic in kernel code, and I understand the reasons why the kernel doesn't allow that.  What I am trying to do exactly is to load a module and calculate the elapsed time in seconds since the time the kernel module has been loaded and removed. I know how to do that using the value of jiffies and HZ like this:

```
#include <linux/jiffies.h>
unsigned long int first_jiff;

int start_init(void){
    first_jiff = jiffies;
    printk(KERN_INFO "loading kernel module\n");
    return 0;
}

void exit_init(void){
   float elapsed_seconds;
   //calculate the difference between first value of jiffies and the current one
   first_jiff = jiffies - first_jiff;

   elapsed_seconds = (float)(first_jiff / HZ);
   printk(KERN_INFO "elapsed_time:%f", elapsed_seconds);
}
module_init(start_init);
module_exit(exit_init);
```

but of course, I get this error

```
/include/linux/printk.h:464:44: error: SSE register return with SSE disabled
```

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: You have not shown what `HZ` is. If it is an integer value then the quotient `elapsed_seconds = first_jiff / HZ;` will not be a floating point division. But why do you have `float elapsed_seconds;` when you are passing it to `%d` format specifier? It seems muddled.

Comment: @WeatherVane sorry for my mistake, the code is right now, the HZ represents the number of CPU time interrupts per second

Comment: So why isn't `float elapsed_seconds;` as `double elapsed_seconds;` since you made the`(double)` cast? And the cast doesn't prevent integer division. It would need to be `elapsed_seconds = (float)first_jiff / HZ;`

Comment: @WeatherVane again sorry i was searching for hours for a solution, so i am a bit exhausted, anyway the code is fixed

Comment: Just use [jiffies_to_usecs()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/jiffies.h#L290), jiffies_to_msecs(), jiffies64_to_nsecs(), or jiffies64_to_msecs() for the conversion, depending on the resolution you want.  The results are also integer types.

Comment: Use integer arithmetic. Define your mantissa and exponent, prepare values separately (you have usually 64-bit values available, by proper multiplications and divisions you may get those (see how IIO subsystem handles that).

Comment: Also couple of remarks regarding the `printf()` calls. Use `pr_info(...)`  instead of `printk(KERN_INFO ...)` and don't forget trailing `\n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need floating point types here.  Just do the division, which will be integer division, and store the result in an integer.

```
void exit_init(void){
   unsigned long elapsed_seconds;
   //calculate the difference between first value of jiffies and the current one
   first_jiff = jiffies - first_jiff;

   elapsed_seconds = first_jiff / HZ;
   printk(KERN_INFO "elapsed_time:%lu", elapsed_seconds);
}
```

Comment: @th3plus do you require the fractional part? If so, why?

Comment: @ShaneBishop not really but i wanna know if there's a way to do it,

Comment: @th3plus Because you're doing integer division,, the fractional part is truncated.

Comment: @dbush but what if i want to do floating point division

Comment: @th3plus You're in kernel code, so you can't.

Comment: @dbush so there's no workaround to do fraction arithmetic right in kernel code? thank you for your help

Comment: @th3plus if you have headroom you can multiply up before dividing, and stuff a decimal point into the text for output.

Comment: @WeatherVane if you can give me an example ,i would be really  grateful,

Comment: Sth like `int a = b * 100 / 5; printf("%d.%02d", a / 100, a % 100);`

Comment: For dividing say `int b = 123` by `5` and showing 2 decimal places, that output is `24.60`

Comment: If you want the 'fractional' part of the seconds, you get it by using `int frac = first_jiffies % HZ;` — the fraction is `frac` units of `1 / HZ` seconds.